# Access to Lightning Console Developer API from third-party app

Tags: lightning, api, console

I am trying to access to Console Developer API from my third party app in javascript (an Open CTI app).

I can do this with no problem in console classic loading this sdk: 
`login.salesforce.com/support/console/42.0/integration.js`, found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_connecting.htm

My question is simple: How and where do I find the URL to load this SDK in Lightning?

Thanks :)